# Ajax pagination with one time record in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on one hotels project where m requesting for hotels record. That API gives me thousands of record at a time in return. I want to do pagination with this record.
The problem m facing is i dont want to call API back. I want to use those record which API gave me first time.
I want to use it and apply pagination using ajax request.
Is that posible?
Or there is any another better way to do it?

Comment: Can you provide relevant code you have got already with structure of data returned by API? Basically, you should use API returned data same way that is used data returned from DB i.e.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataTable to help you make ajax pagination
https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Actually I dont want to use datatable and event dont want to call API on every page request. I just want to call API once and use it for pagination, because API takes charges for every call.

Comment: Is there any way to use data or can store it globally and use it?

Comment: datatable supports pagination without any additional requests, just one request for all records and it create a pagination, also you can use the browser database for your temporary data from the api, also you can save the request to your server database and reuse it again if possible to save some requests charges